# Using secrets from AWS Secrets Manager in a CDK stack using ECS + Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, aws-fargate, aws-secrets-manager

I have defined a CDK app stack using TypeScript (sensitive information rendomized in the code below):

```js
import * as cdk from "@aws-cdk/core";
import * as ec2 from "@aws-cdk/aws-ec2";
import * as ecs from "@aws-cdk/aws-ecs";
import * as ecr from "@aws-cdk/aws-ecr";
import * as ecr_assets from "@aws-cdk/aws-ecr-assets";
import * as ecs_patterns from "@aws-cdk/aws-ecs-patterns";
import * as sm from "@aws-cdk/aws-secretsmanager";

export class CdkAppStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // Create a Docker image and upload it to the Amazon Elastic Container Registry (ECR)
    const dockerImage = new ecr_assets.DockerImageAsset(this, "ApiDockerImage", {
      directory: "/home/ec2-user/environment/node-test"
    });

    // Create a new VPC and NAT Gateway
    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, "ApiVpc", {
      maxAzs: 3 // Default is all AZs in region
    });

    // Create a new Amazon Elastic Container Service (ECS) cluster
    const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, "ApiCluster", {
      vpc: vpc
    });

    // Create a load-balanced Fargate service and make it public
    new ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(this, "ApiFargateService", {
      cluster: cluster, // Required
      cpu: 512, // Default is 256
      desiredCount: 2, // Default is 1
      taskImageOptions: {
        image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromDockerImageAsset(dockerImage),
        containerPort: 8080,
        enableLogging: true,
        secrets: sm.Secret.fromSecretCompleteArn(this, "ImportedSecret", "arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-south-1:762589711820:secret:/api/production/FrOibp")
      },
      memoryLimitMiB: 2048, // Default is 512
      publicLoadBalancer: true // Default is false
    });
  }
}
```

Deployment with `cdk deploy` is successful if I remove the `secrets` key from `taskImageOptions` but with the `secrets` there, I get this error when trying to deploy:

```
ec2-user:~/environment/cdk-app (master) $ cdk deploy
⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
lib/cdk-app-stack.ts:42:9 - error TS2322: Type 'ISecret' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: Secret; }'.
  Index signature is missing in type 'ISecret'.

42         secrets: secret
           ~~~~~~~

Subprocess exited with error 1
```

I'm doing something wrong here in trying to use secrets from Secrets Manager. What is the right way to reference secrets in a `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. `secrets` is of type index signature. you should therefore name your secret (this is the environment variable that will be exposed in your container)
2. an `ecs.Secret` is expected (you can create it from an `sm.Secret`)

here is a working version:

```js
new ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(this, "ApiFargateService", {
  cluster: cluster, // Required
  cpu: 512, // Default is 256
  desiredCount: 2, // Default is 1
  taskImageOptions: {
    image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromDockerImageAsset(dockerImage),
    containerPort: 8080,
    enableLogging: true,
    secrets: {
      "MY_SECRET": ecs.Secret.fromSecretsManager( sm.Secret.fromSecretCompleteArn(this, "ImportedSecret", "arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-south-1:762589711820:secret:/api/production/FrOibp"))
    }
  },
  memoryLimitMiB: 2048, // Default is 512
  publicLoadBalancer: true // Default is false
});
```